# Доработка функции на php: нужна помощь

Tags: php

Есть две разные cookie:

`Cart` содержит ID товара и количество этого товара в заказе. Пример:

`{"227":2,"235":1,"242":1,"243":3}`

`cart_info` содержит ID товара и размеры этого товара в заказе. В вышеуказанном примере:

`{"227":["XL","4XL"],"235":["3XL"],"242":["L"],"243":["M","L","XL"]}`

Функция обработки `cart`:

```html
$items = (array)json_decode(stripslashes(@$_COOKIE['cart']), true);
$products = $this->model->product->getByIds(array_keys($items));            
$orders2 = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $count = array_key_exists($product->id, $items) ? $items[$product->id] : 1;
    $count = preg_match('@^[0-9]+$@i', $count) ? $count : 1;
    $orders2[] = $product->name . ' (' . $count . ' шт);';
}
```

Результат:  `Товар227 (2 шт); Товар235 (1 шт); Товар242 (1 шт); Товар243 (3 шт);`

Функция обработки `cart_info`:

```html
        $items_info = (array)json_decode(stripslashes(@$_COOKIE['cart_info']), true);
        $message_info = "";
        foreach ($items_info as $key => $val) {
            $message_info .=  $this->model->product->getById($key)->name . ": " . implode(',', array_unique($val)) . " // ";
        }
```

Результат:`Товар227: XL,4XL // Товар235: 3XL // Товар242: L // Товар243: M,L,XL //`

Помогите написать третью функцию, которая объединит данные и даст результат вида:

`Товар227 (2 шт): XL,4XL // Товар235 (1 шт): 3XL // Товар242 (1 шт): L // Товар243 (3 шт): M,L,XL //`

Comment: надеюсь вы хоть сами то замечаете, что когда мешаешь логику обработки и логику вывода, то получается как-то сложновато?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете в функции обработки `cart_info` собирать информацию в массив, а вывод делать через `implode(string, delimiter)`, где в качестве индекса массива писать `$this->model->product->getById($key)->id`, то есть будет:

```
$cartInfo[$this->model->product->getById($key)->id] = $this->model->product->getById($key)->name . ": " . implode(',', array_unique($val));
```

В функции 1 сделать аналогично - индекс массива = ид товара.

```
 $orders2[$product->id] = $product->name . ' (' . $count . ' шт);';
```

И в конце что-то типо:

```
foreach($orders2 as $productId => $order){
    echo $order.':'.$cartInfo[$productId];
}
```